# Display multiple values from query with formating

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

This is my current code

```
$goalquery = "SELECT goal FROM Goals";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($goalquery))
$goal = $result->fetch_row();

foreach($goal as $value){
   ?> My goal is <?php echo $value;
 }
```

and it displays 
[image]

But it should return at least 3 values for `$goal`

It should say...

```
My goal is to hang my clothing
My goal is to drink less coffee
My goal is to go to the gym everyday
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of fetching a row i think you might want to [**`fetch associations`**](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc)

```
$goal = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

From documentation

> - Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.

[**`fecth_row()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) function you used will only return one row

> - Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset starting from 0 (zero). Each subsequent call to this function will return the next row within the result set, or NULL if there are no more rows.